# sqlite3 python fetch not working as expected

Tags: python, sqlite

For some reason these lines are not working as expected:

```
for duplicate in duplicates: 
    c.execute("SELECT * FROM " + tablename + " WHERE id=?", (duplicate,))
    game_info = c.fetchone()
```

`duplicate` is a string and the table has an `id`, `title` and `tags` columns each text.

I also called a commit right before this block of code, and the info that it is trying to select is definitely there 
for some reason `game_info` is NONE and I can't figure out why.

Comment: Please show all the code that is relevant. The connection, the cursor, how `duplicates` is instantiated, etc.

Comment: Obviously, there is no row with a matching `id` value. Either the database or the `duplicate` variable does not contain what you expect.